# Message "Error while trying to parse JSON" in Notepad++ while editing

Tags: notepad++

Whenever I try to edit a `.json` file in Notepad++, I periodically get this dialog box:

[image: Could not parse the document because of error Unterminated string literal at position 93 (char 'T')]

This makes the editing process unusable, since obviously the format is going to be invalid during the editing process!

Is there a way to fix this behaviour?

Comment: I don't think Notepad++ does any JSON parsing out-of-the-box. Are you using a plugin to parse JSON? If so, could you edit your question to include that?

Comment: I have plugins installed (JStool and JsonTools), but I'm not doing anything to "activate" them, just editing a `.json` file.

Comment: Do you happen to have JsonTools installed, and in its settings panel have `auto_validate` set to `True`?

Comment: yes!!  I just changed it to `False`.  Hopefully, that fixes it! Thanks!